# MongoDB - Advantage of using 12 bytes string as unique identifier instead of incremental value

Tags: mongodb, nosql, uuid

Is there any specific reason for MongoDB generating uuid as unique identifier instead of incremental values as unique identifier?.

Comment: It's not a UUID but an ObjectID. Those are completely different things

Comment: @NeilLunn The answers for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560928/why-mongodb-uses-objectid clarifies why mongodb uses ObjectID. My question why mondodb doesn't use incremental value and does generate 12 bit Identifier

Comment: Incrementing values or sequences require a central point of reference which is a limiting factor for scaling. ObjectIDs are designed to be reasonably unique IDs that can be independently generated in a distributed environment with monotonically increasing values for approximate ordering. ObjectIDs are typically generated by drivers so there is no need to make a server round-trip to find the next available `_id `or wait for the server result of an insert to know what `_id` was allocated. You can provide your own `_id` values if you prefer not to use ObjectIDs. ObjectIDs are 12 bytes (not bits).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Incrementing values or sequences require a central point of reference which is a limiting factor for scaling. ObjectIDs are designed to be reasonably unique IDs that can be independently generated in a distributed environment with monotonically increasing values (a leading timestamp component) for approximate ordering.

ObjectIDs are typically generated by MongoDB drivers so there is no need to make a server round-trip to find the next available `_id` or wait for the server result of an insert operation to know what `_id` was allocated. If a driver or client application inserts a document without including an `_id` value, an ObjectID will be generated by the `mongod` server.

There is no strict requirement to use ObjectIDs in MongoDB: you can provide your own `_id` values if there is a more natural unique key for your data or you prefer an alternative primary key format.