# nested map() and find() do not work in express + mongoose but work in codesandbox

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I got a route in express that get 2 different array of object from mongoDb and then return a new "contributions" array after i've added some data into it from "projectAll"

Here is one contributions object:

```
  {
    _id: "5f5b095f01ba8e40769f7301",
    libId: "5f5a7a7701ba8e40769f72fb",
    totalPaidAmount: 10000,
    transactionId: "pi_1HQ4hVGmJhXXrXOXnr0pkXkv",
    cart: [
      {
        _id: "5f5b095f01ba8e40769f7302",
        amount: 5000,
        projectId: "5f5b086601ba8e40769f72fe"
      },
      {
        _id: "5f5b095f01ba8e40769f7303",
        amount: 5000,
        projectId: "5f5b08ae01ba8e40769f7300"
      }
    ],
    __v: 0
 }
```

And one projectAll object:

```
  {
    projectCover: { id: "211290" },
    title: "My title 2",
    funded: 11000,
    description: "Desc",
    _id: "5f5b08ae01ba8e40769f7300",
    libId: "5f5a7a7701ba8e40769f72fb",
    __v: 0
  }
```

I need to add projectAll.title and projectAll.projectCover into each contributions.cart objects.
To do so I match contribution.cart.projectId with projectAll._id.

```
router.get("/contributions/:id", async (req, res) => {
       const id = req.params.id
      
       try {
       const contributions = await Contribution.find({id})
       const projectAll = await Project.find({id})

       const updatedContribution = contributions.map((contribution) => {

            // Go through each cart of each contribution
            const updatedCart = contribution.cart.map((cartItem) => {

                // Find matching project
                const matchingProject = projectAll.find((project) => {

                    // project OK =====>  console.log(project)
                    // projectAll OK =====>  console.log(projectAll)
                    // cartItem OK =====>  console.log(cartItem)

                    return project._id === cartItem.projectId;

                });

                // Here return undefined =====>  console.log(matchingProject)

                const {projectCover, title} = matchingProject

                return {...cartItem, projectCover, title
                }
            })

            return { ...contribution, cart: updatedCart
            }
        })

        res.send(updatedContribution)
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err)
    }
```

this code work perfectly in my codeSandBox : https://codesandbox.io/s/contribution-map-projects-vhv8z?file=/src/index.js

But in my express + mongoose environment I get undefined for matchingProject (i added comments in the code to show from where I get unwanted result)

Does anybody know why it doesn't work ?
Thanks a lot !

EDIT:  console.log(typeof project._id, typeof cartItem.projectId) return object object
whereas in codesandbox those are strings.

Comment: also the code in codesandbox isn't reflecting express and mongoose environment as I don't know how to set everything from there. but function is working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they are both ObjectIds you can use mongoose equals() functions - so `project._id.equals(cartItem.projectId)`. You cannot compare them, cause you'd compare their object reference. So either the above function will work or `project._id.toString() === cartItem.projectId.toString()`

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment, indeed when I console.log(typeof project._id, typeof cartItem.projectId) I get object object
but i don't understand how. The .toString() doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @NuoNuoLeRobot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560928/why-mongodb-uses-objectid -> here it is nicely explained. About your problem - I edited my answer

Comment: My first answer was wrong, cause I guessed that you keep projectId in string, but it is actually ObjectId